# Override sails update to return just one object

Tags: arrays, callback, sails.js, sails-postgresql, waterlock

When I update a model, waterlock `.update()` always return an array of objects, even if I set on criteria a `primaryKey`.

**on my code**

```
Ad.update({ id: req.param('id') }, {
    // desired attributed to be updated
}).exec(function(err, updatedRecord) {
    // updatedRecord is always an array of objects
});
```

And in order to use the updatedRecord, I have to point out to `0` index like `updatedRecord[0]` which is something I consider not very clean. According to docs [update() in sails](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update#notes), this is a common escenario.

Knowing that, I have 2 questions:

1. Wouldn't be better that when you find one model return just a updated object for that model, not an array?
2. If that is a convention, **how could be overrided this function in order to return just an object instead of an array when `.update()` have only affected one record?**

Answer (score 1):

it is a convention that it will update all the records that matches the find criteria, but as you are probably using a **unique** validation on model, it will probably return an array of 1 or 0. You need to do it on hand.

You can override methods in model, by implementing a method with same name as waterline default. But as you will need to completely rewrite the code, it is not viable. Neither changing waterline underlying code.

A solution will be creating a new function on your Ad model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    adid: {
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    updateMe: {
    }
  },
  updateOne: function(adid, newUpdateMe, cb){
    Ad.update({ id: req.param('id') }, {
    // desired attributed to be updated
    }).exec(function(err, updatedRecord) {
        // updatedRecord is always an array of objects
        if (updatedRecord.length == 1){
          return cb(null, updatedRecord[0]);
        }
        return cb(null, {}); //also can error if not found.
    });    
  }
};
```

Also. Avoid using id as an model attribute (use other name), as some databases like mongodb already add this attribute as default and may cause conflicts with your model.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible with waterline. Its because update method is a generalized one, passing a primary key in where condition is always not the case.